# setting StepExecutionContext before step run in Spring Batch

Tags: spring-batch

I would like to run a worker step by a manager step.

Before running the worker step, I need to set some parameters on the StepExecutionContext of the worker step (done by the manager step).

Is this possible? If not do I have alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

We are not going to use "Master/Slave" terms any more in Spring Batch and we will replace them with "Manager/Worker" (See [BATCH-2834](https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2834)). So I'm going to use these new terms here.

In a Manager/Worker setup, the manager passes information required by worker steps in a form of a `StepExecutionContext`. The component responsible for creating these execution contexts is the [`Partitioner`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/partition/support/Partitioner.html). The partitioner is the piece that understands the data and knows how to partition it for workers. So this is where you would add additional data.

Take a look at the [SimplePartitioner](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/core/partition/support/SimplePartitioner.java#L33) or [ColumnRangePartitioner](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-samples/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/sample/common/ColumnRangePartitioner.java#L36) to get an idea.

Comment: Thank You. As I understand the partitioner is creating execution contexts a head and only then devide the population to step execution contexts. hence I am not using the partitioner but creating by myself a manager step that triggers X worker steps.

Comment: In that case, please edit the question and share your code to understand what you are trying to achieve. I'll try to help you by showing where you could add the information in the execution context.